# LED keeps turned on after I first turn on the button

Tags: arduino

I am trying to transform a push button into a switch by setting the variable e to 1 or 0 depending on whether pin 12 returns HIGH or LOW, but after pressing the button a single time, the led turns on and doesn't turn off no matter how many times I press the button again.

````
#define boton 12
#define gled 7
#define rled 4
#define yled 8

int e=0;
int botonst=LOW;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(boton,INPUT);
  pinMode(gled,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rled,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yled,OUTPUT);



}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  botonst=digitalRead(boton);
  if ((botonst==HIGH) && (e=1)){
    
    digitalWrite(yled,HIGH);
    e=0;
    
  }
  
  else{
    if(e=0){
      digitalWrite(yled,LOW);
      e=1;
        }
    }
      

  
  delay(50);
      
    

  
}

```C
````

Comment: You should try writing out what your logic really says.  It will become clear.

Comment: `e=1` is not a comparison. And do you have a pull-down resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic is not clear! but i guess that you have button and led and try to toggle led every time you click on the button if that what you try to do ..then use this code

```
#define boton 12   // button conect on pin 12
#define yled 8     // led conect on pin 8

bool ledMode = false;   // this  mode use to save the current led state ( high or low ) 
int botonst=LOW;     
 
void setup() {
  pinMode(boton,INPUT); // make button as input pin
  pinMode(yled,OUTPUT); // make led as output pin
}

void loop() {
  botonst=digitalRead(boton); // read the button state
  if (botonst==HIGH){            // if button is clicked  (assume you connect the button as active high)
    ledMode ^= true;             // toggle the mode (if it true make it false and if it false make it ture)
    if(ledMode == false)         //if led mod is off
        digitalWrite(yled,HIGH);   // turn led on
     else                        // if led mode is on
        digitalWrite(yled,LOW);     // turn led off
  }
  delay(200);   //delay for Depounceing (if you use hardware Depounce technique remove it)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much